# Use find() on embedded arrays with jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to loop through embedded arrays until I find an item whose `data` property corresponds with my input.

The example below should alert *Netherlands*. Instead, when you use an item in the first array you get `undefined` and if you choose one from the second you get an object.

```js
var countries = {
  "EU": [
    {value: 'Malta', data: 'MT'},
    {value: 'Netherlands', data: 'NL'},
    {value: 'Austria', data: 'AT'},
    {value: 'Italy', data: 'IT'}
  ],
  "other": [
    {value: 'Bosnia and Herz.', data: 'BA'},
    {value: 'Jersey', data: 'JE'},
    {value: 'Belarus', data: 'BY'}
  ]
};


function findCountry(code) {
  $.each(countries, function(key, arr) {
    val = arr.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.data == code;
    });
  });
  return val;
}
  
alert(findCountry('NL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I think that even if the item is found in the first array, the `each` keeps running. A return statement is probably needed instead. But even then,

```js
var countries = {
  "EU": [
    {value: 'Malta', data: 'MT'},
    {value: 'Netherlands', data: 'NL'},
    {value: 'Austria', data: 'AT'},
    {value: 'Italy', data: 'IT'}
  ],
  "other": [
    {value: 'Bosnia and Herz.', data: 'BA'},
    {value: 'Jersey', data: 'JE'},
    {value: 'Belarus', data: 'BY'}
  ]
};


function findCountry(code) {
  $.each(countries, function(key, arr) {
    return arr.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.data == code;
    });
  });
}
  
alert(findCountry('BA'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But this returns `undefined` all the time. So what am I missing?

Comment: The issue is that `findCountry()` has no return, thus it is `undefined`

Comment: If you are looking up the country (and not the "region") you should structure your object with the country name as the key and the region as some property of the sub-object.  Then just check `if (countries['Malta'])` rather than searching through the whole object's properties.

Comment: @James I wish I could change the structure, unfortunately I am using a plugin that requires this specific structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of current answers and some more experimenting.

```js
var countries = {
  "EU": [
    {value: 'Malta', data: 'MT'},
    {value: 'Netherlands', data: 'NL'},
    {value: 'Austria', data: 'AT'},
    {value: 'Italy', data: 'IT'}
  ],
  "other": [
    {value: 'Bosnia and Herz.', data: 'BA'},
    {value: 'Jersey', data: 'JE'},
    {value: 'Belarus', data: 'BY'}
  ]
};


function findCountry(code) {
  var val;
  $.each(countries, function(key, arr) {
    val = arr.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.data == code;
    });
    // If value is found, exit early
    if (val) return false;
  });
  
  // If value found, return it, else return undefined
  return val ? val.value : undefined;
}
  
console.log(findCountry('MP'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can do this without jQuery as well, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result of the `$.each()` within the `findCountry()` function. It has no `return` in your example and is thus `undefined`. I removed the `var val` as well since you aren't assigning anything to it.

```
function findCountry(code) {
  return $.each(countries, function(key, arr) {
    return arr.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.data == code;
    });
  });
}
```

To just return the name of the matching country you can use pure Javascript (no jQuery needed) and make it efficient by using the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to loop through the object and the [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to exit early when you find a match.

```
var countries = {
  "EU": [
    {value: 'Malta', data: 'MT'},
    {value: 'Netherlands', data: 'NL'},
    {value: 'Austria', data: 'AT'},
    {value: 'Italy', data: 'IT'}
  ],
  "other": [
    {value: 'Bosnia and Herz.', data: 'BA'},
    {value: 'Jersey', data: 'JE'},
    {value: 'Belarus', data: 'BY'}
  ]
};

function findCountry(code) {
  var name = null;
  Object.keys(countries).some(function(key) {       // Go through EU, other, ...
    return countries[key].some(function(country) {  // Check the array under each key
        if (country.data === code) {                // check the code against the data value
            name = country.value;                   // set the name to the value
        }
        return name !== null;                       // a true result will exit some()
    });
  });                                               // this some() will also exit when we get a result
  return name;                                      // return the name value we found
}

console.log(findCountry('BA'));
```

This will output `Bosnia and Herz.` as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/yybgn2jg/1/

Comment: ES6 Lambdas can reduce that to one line :D

Comment: Technically I could write that all out on one line too :P

Comment: `return $.each(countries, (key, arr) => arr.find(obj => obj.data == code));`

Comment: Why have a `return` at all?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The ES6 example looks 'cool', but it is not really readable for me yet as I'm not familiar with ES6. I'd like to use the 'normal' one :-) (Which does not work at the moment.)

Comment: @BramVanroy I was just showing why it was returning undefined, give me a sec and ill update it.

Comment: You need a temp var to store the the found object. You then return it.
like so https://jsfiddle.net/2szy0Lth/2/

Comment: @VladimirDrenovski That's correct I missed the first part of the question and only explained why it was `undefined`, I've updated it to use pure Javascript to find the value.

Answer (score -1):

You just forgot some return statement of the find function

```js
var countries = {
  "EU": [
    {value: 'Malta', data: 'MT'},
    {value: 'Netherlands', data: 'NL'},
    {value: 'Austria', data: 'AT'},
    {value: 'Italy', data: 'IT'}
  ],
  "other": [
    {value: 'Bosnia and Herz.', data: 'BA'},
    {value: 'Jersey', data: 'JE'},
    {value: 'Belarus', data: 'BY'}
  ]
};


function findCountry(code) {
  var result;

  $.each(countries, function(key, arr) {
    var countryRes = arr.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.data == code;
    });
    if (countryRes) {
       result = countryRes;
    }
       
  });

  return result && result.value;
}
  
alert(findCountry('JE'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work when you choose an item from the first array.